# Delay javascript function for few seconds

Tags: javascript

On clicking this button my script runs the function `manage($n)`

```
$onclick = "manage('$n');";
```

but I want to refresh the page as soon as the page is hit.

```
$onclick="window.location.reload(true);manage('$n')";
```

Since the refresh is fast I want to delay manage function for 3 seconds before running, but the delay is not working.

```
$onclick="window.location.reload(true);setTimeout(manage('$n'),300);";

<input class='button' onclick=\"$onclick\" ></td>
```

Comment: Why are you writing JavaScript as a string? Look into `addEventListener`.

Comment: I don't understand why you want to run the function after the page is reloaded.

Comment: when the page is reloaded a lot of authentication and session checks are enfored which i dont want to include in javascript or ajax..all i want to do is whenever a button is hit-> the page reloads and the usual function(manage ) runs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this:

```
$onclick="window.location.reload(true);setTimeout(function(){manage('$n')},3000);";
```

**Edit**

`window.location.reload` reload the page and reinitialize javascript. So You can't wait for it to complete. Also this can't have any callback. So you need to run `manage` function on `document.ready()`. You can set a cookie before reload the page.  After reload, check if cookie sets, run `manage` function:

```
 $onclick="document.cookie='reload=true';window.location.reload(true);"
```

Now, add this code in the head of the page:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   if (document.cookie.indexOf("reload") >= 0)
   {
        manage('$n');
        //set expires parameter to a passed date for deleting cookie
        document.cookie = "reload=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC"; 
   }
});
```

I think cookie is a good and possible solution for you. For reading more about javascript cookies, [refer to this link.](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

Comment: wouldn't that reload the page immediately and manage() never get invoked?

Comment: thank you for the help but it didn't help. all i wanted was to run the manage function once the reload is complete.

Comment: yes manage wasn't invoked..i want to reload and invoke manage after the reload

Comment: @fundakaymak: `window.location.reload(true)` reload the page and reinitialize the javascript. So you can't wait for it to complete or add callback for it.

Comment: any suggestions on what should i do instead?

Comment: @hamed : actually this was just a bit of the bigger picture..manage function fires a post ajax request and the simpler solution was to redirect in ajax but that didnt work as well (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29046459/unable-to-redirect-in-ajax-file)..anyways mate i really appreciate for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you could try like this

```
if(!window.location.callAfterRelod)
     {
        var a={};
        a.manage=manage;
        window.location.callAfterReload=JSON.stringify(a);
        window.location.reload(true);
     }
else
    JSON.parse(window.location.callAfterReload).manage($n);
```